# Swift: Error when updated Xcode: 'could not find overload for '&&' that accepts the supplied arguments'

Tags: swift, xcode6

I just updated to the non beta version of Xcode 6 (finally) and, coming from beta 5, got a few errors that I didn't get before, one being "could not find overload for '&&' that accepts the supplied arguments"

I am following a tutorial here and from another question, I know that this error is because "the expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions." 
I'm a beginner; how do I break up an expression into sub-expressions?

My code:

```
func checkForWin(){
        //first row across
        var youWin = 1
        var theyWin = 0
        var whoWon = ["Lost":0,"Won":1]
        for (key,value) in whoWon {
            if ((plays[6] == value && plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value) || //across the bottom
            (plays[3] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value) || //across the middle
            (plays[0] == value && plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value) || //across the top
            (plays[6] == value && plays[3] == value && plays[0] == value) || //down the left side
            (plays[7] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[1] == value) || //down the middle
            (plays[8] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[2] == value) || //down the right side
            (plays[6] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[2] == value) || //diagonal
                (plays[8] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[0] == value)){//diagonal
                    userMessage.hidden = false
                    youLabel.hidden = false
                    userMessage.text = "\(key)!"
                    done = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var plays = [Int:Int]()`

Answer (score 0):

To break it up, you just need to add more ()s. Like this:

```
 if (((plays[6] == value) && (plays[7] == value) && (plays[8] == value)) ||
 ((plays[3] == value) && (plays[4] == value) && (plays[5] == value)) ||
 ((plays[0] == value) && (plays[1] == value) && (plays[2] == value)) ||

 ((plays[8] == value) && (plays[4] == value) && (plays[0] == value)))
```